# Regarding the problem when the Scanner class in Java reads text content and uses StringBuffer.append to splice it

Tags: java

**The problem occurs when the Scanner class in Java reads text content and uses StringBuffer.append to splice it.**

I have just started to learn Java. I have encountered a small problem in the past two days. I can't figure it out even if I ask gpt, so I would like to ask everyone for help. Since the question is relatively basic, I hope you can forgive me.
The code show as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Learn01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("d:" + File.separator + "test.txt"));
            scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int flag =0;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            str.append(scanner.next());
            str.append("//");
            str.append("\n");
            flag++;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println("finish");
        System.out.println(flag);
    }
}
```

The text content is as follows:
hello a
hello b
hello c
hello d
hello e

But the result of running is:

```
//  
//  
//  
//  
hello e//  
  
finish  
5
```

The content of the first four lines is gone, and only the text content of the last line is printed. In order to make it obvious, I specially added '//' and also added a flag value in the loop to prove that it has indeed entered the While loop 5 times.
But when I comment out the sentence `str.append("//");` and it becomes `str.append(scanner.next());str.append("\n");`, the program will run normally and print out the results.
I want to ask why this is?

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter("\n");` If you are on Windows and the lines end with `\r\n`, the `\r` will be read into the string and printed. (Although I would expect that to print `//llo a`, etc.)

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes,I am using Windows system.

Comment: Then get rid of `scanner.useDelimiter("\n");` and change `scanner.next()` to `scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: Use `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R");` This will cover all new-line circumstances including Unicode.  Or, as already commented....Get rid of the **Scanner#useDelimiter()** method and use the **Scanner#hasNextLine()** and **Scanner#nextLine()** methods. Be sure to also **close** your file reader to release the file and free resources (`scanner.close()` after the `while` loop).